# user_type model when I tried to use it registerusers.php I have Class 'app\user_type' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make a user role and use it during registration to use it at login. 
So Ii made user_type model but when I use it in registerUsers.php, which is in vendor directory, I have this error:

```
Class 'app\user_type' not found
```

this is the registerUsers.php

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

use \app\user_type;

trait RegistersUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $users_types=user_type::all();
        return view('auth.register')->with('users_types',$users_types);
    }
```

I want to use the result of this query in my registration view and I want to choose a user role from user_type model

Comment: Hi, do you have `UserType` Model?

Answer (score 0):

The proper (standard) namespace for models is `App\Model`.

Your model classes should all have a capital letter at the start of each word and no underscores, according to PSRs. (StudlyCase).

So to fix your issue, you should try something like:

```php
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use App\UserType;


....

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $userTypes = UserType::all();

        return view('auth.register', [
            'userTypes' => $userTypes,
        ]);
    }
....
```

Comment: I renamed the model in both app and registerusers controllers but it still not working